# Delaying a Spring WebClient call with ScheduledExecutorService does not wait for response

Tags: java, spring-boot

Given a simple REST controller and service method (Spring Boot 2.5.x and Java 8) how can I achieve the following?

1. A client posts some data to the REST controller.
2. The controller calls the service method.
3. The service method shall invoke a REST call to an external API using the `WebClient` **after a fixed delay** of e.g. 10 s.

While 1. and 2. are trivial, I struggle with 3. My first implementation looks like this, using a `ScheduledExecutorService`. This actually delays the execution of `sendNotification()` but it seems as if the result of this REST call is ignored. If the external API returns an e.g. HTTP 4xx/5xx, I would expect a `WebClientResponseException` but this does not happen.

Maybe this has something to do with the `ScheduledExecutorService` and some thread issue?

**REST Controller class**

```java
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ServiceController {

    private final SampleService sampleService;

    @PostMapping(value = "/api")
    public String create(@RequestBody SampleRequest sampleRequest) {
        return sampleService.create(sampleRequest);
    }
}
```

**Service class**

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SampleService {

    private final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    public String create(SampleRequest sampleRequest) {
        final String result = processSampleRequest(sampleRequest);
        executorService.schedule(() -> sendNotification(), 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return result;
    }

    public void sendNotification() {
        final WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .build();
        webClient.post()
                .uri("http://localhost:5555")
                .body(BodyInserters.fromValue("some string"))
                .retrieve()
                .toBodilessEntity()
                .block();    
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't handle exception in sendNotification, let add try/catch ... and i wonder what do you do with this exception? Throw it in service or something?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me into the right direction. This is what I think is happening: The controller actually has finished its work while `sendNotification()` is running "outside" the controller context. Thus, my `RestControllerAdvice` doesn't kick in.

Comment: Yeah, if you want to RestControllerAdvice catch your exception, so you must throw it inside service, so executorService is meaningless here, because you have to wait the result of webclient... to check status error... something is quite confused in your requirement

Comment: What should happen on the client side if `sendNotification` fails? Is this response of any meaning to the client? Currently the client will immediately receive the result string and any error in `sendNotification` will happen unnoticed.